# C# Linq or Lambda to get Dictionary<string, List<string>> from a class

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda

I cannot seem to find the answer I am looking for. Hopefully someone here can help out.

I have a class that contains setting information for some processes. Each class has a processId, taskId, and various other pieces of information not needed for my current logic.

```
public class ProcessSetting
{
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    // Other properties not needed
}
```

There are multiple ProcessSettings that can exist. I am pulling the data into a List. It is possible to have a processId associated with multiple TaskIds. For example:

```
ProcessId: 1, TaskId: 1
ProcessId: 1, TaskId: 1
ProcessId: 1, TaskId: 2
ProcessId: 1, TaskId: 3
ProcessId: 2, TaskId: 3
ProcessId: 2, TaskId: 4
ProcessId: 3, TaskId: 1
```

I am initially using linq to just gather the values that I need from the existing enum: (Using distinct at the end to avoid pulling in the multiple record set of ProcessId 1 and TaskId 1)

```
var baseSettings = (from setting in processSettings
                    select new
                              {
                                  ProcessStr = ((ProcessEnum)setting.ProcessId).ToString(),
                                  TaskStr = ((TaskEnum)setting.TaskId).ToString()
                              }).Distinct();
```

This now gives me a list with just the processId and taskId. I found some logic on here that lead me in the right direction, but isn't exactly what I need. Here is what that was:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string> = baseSettings.GroupBy(x => x.ProcessStr).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

However, This is incorrect. I am getting an error:

> "Cannot convert source type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Generic.List{ProcessStr:string,
>   TaskStr:string}>>` to target type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>`

I don't want a Key with a value of {ProcessStr, TaskStr}. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry, can't understand what data you need in your dictionary

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `x.ToList` you have to select the string property of the anonymous type first:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> procTasks = baseSettings
    .GroupBy(x => x.ProcessStr)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.TaskStr).ToList());
```

Comment: Can't translate this `Dictionary<string, List<string> = baseSettings`?

Comment: @KingKing: Thanks, corrected. Haven't seen that the syntax was broken.