# Dictionary with single key multiple values in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query which I want to put in a dictionary. My dictionary is

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

How can I put a query below into the defined dictionary?

```
...
...
select new
   {
     b.PropertyName             
     a.PropertyValue,
     a.PropertyOrder,
   }).Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.PropertyName, 
    x => x.ToList() // The rest of the two values should be in the list
    );
```

Comment: take a look at this perhaps this can shed some light / and or Ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640141/c-sharp-linq-or-lambda-to-get-dictionarystring-liststring-from-a-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select new {
b.PropertyName
a.PropertyValue,
a.PropertyOrder})
.Distinct()
.ToDictionary(key => key.PropertyName, 
value => new List<string>{ value.PropertyValue, value.PropertyOrder});
```

Comment: Can you add explanation as to why this works? Code-only answers are discouraged on SO.